# Forum which allows users to download all user-generated content

Tags: linux, open-source, forum

I’m looking for a forum (**FLOSS**; for installation on **GNU/Linux** server) that comes with the following two features, either built-in or available as maintained extension:

#### 1) License for user-generated content

- The admin must be able to globally set the license (e.g., Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0) for all user-generated content.
- The license info needs to be visible on every page which contains user-generated content.
  (I don’t want to add this info manually on the theme-level)
- When users register, they need to confirm that they understand that all their content will be licensed under the chosen license.
  (I don’t want to add this manually to the registration process.)

#### 2) Download of user-generated content

- Everyone who is allowed to post (which may include anonymous users) must be able to download any user-generated content.
- The users should have the choice which user-generated content to download:

  1. of the whole forum
  2. of a single sub-forum
  3. of a single thread
- It should be a machine-readable, "open" format, so something like XML, CSV, zipped text files, HTML etc.
- For each post, the data must contain (besides the actual content):

  - date
  - author name and URL of the profile
  - URL of the post
- The download must also include the license notice, as set by the admin in **1)**.
  It should be contained in each file which contains content, *not* as a separate license.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe won't be an answer but it's getting too long for comments. I'm searching those for an export function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software#General_information

- SMF has some export feature for PM: http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?action=search;basic_search=export
- phpBB no, ends up doing http://nejc.skoberne.net/2011/02/phpbb-export-all-posts-for-a-user-into-a-file/
- MyBB has an ancient mod http://mods.mybb.com/view/export-thread-v1.0.0
- Discourse: admin-only to CSV https://meta.discourse.org/t/improving-import-and-export-support/12110 https://meta.discourse.org/t/export-user-information-list/18960
- Beehive: PM? https://github.com/BeehiveForum/BeehiveForum/blob/master/forum/pm_export.php
- FUDForum: admin-only? http://fudforum.org/forum/index.php?t=msg&th=120851
- eXo: yes, admin-only, also per-category (but also in the community edition?): http://docs.exoplatform.com/public/index.jsp?topic=%2FPLF35%2FForum_Administrator.Administrative_tasks.Back_up_categories_forums.html also a plugin https://community.exoplatform.com/portal/intranet/forum/topic/topicda8f8926c06313bc09486ed60d6ec7df
- Vanilla: for own attachments (?) http://vanillaforums.org/addon/myattachments-plugin or admin-only http://vanillaforums.org/addon/porter-core
- bbPress server-side only https://github.com/pippinsplugins/bbPress-Export-and-Import

I guess this is a no? :[ I'll add these findings to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software#Features if nobody beats me at it.

You might use MediaWiki instead! It has export for everyone. ;)